# ELEX - What does magic spell attribute do

Tags: elex

I have a berserker. All fine. But since PB as usual doesn't really explain all effects of the spells (although I kind of like that from some point of view - kinds of adds to the flare) I fail to understand the full effects of some spells.

For example in print below you see the description of Sense Life spell. What does the "magic 20%" do?

[image]

I think it adds 20% magic while the spell is active. Or adds 20% magic passively? What is the base magic stat (if any1 did some testing... I know there is no character stat page - this is kind of stupid... even gothic 1 had one :)) )?

For some spells like the one above imo that stat could make the difference between being a good spell or something that doesn't worth investing in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The +20% stems from your magic skill in the berserker tree, which should be at 2/5 at the moment.

It increases the effect of the spell. This is my perosnal experience and may very well be different, if people delve deeper to test this.

So, for a damage spell like fireball, this 20% would mean 20% increased damage, for a buff spell like sense life, it means 20% increased duration.

Comment: Yup, figured that up later :)